Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
The error is attached below. What should I do to solve this problem ?
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 16 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           20.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/sony/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1225:25
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16.

I'm expecting to run it in iOS simulator successfully.

The latest version of that plug-in is 6.1.5. You seem to be using 5.8.0. I suggest you update it.

How did you fix the issue
